# Looking for a race condition example that we can use internally in training

Tags: web-application, ctf

I'm making a small CTF for my digital team to teach them about different exploits. I'm hoping to include a race condition example but everything I've found manipulates a local file or SQL database (so multiple users can't follow along at the same time).

Does anybody have a sample race condition I can use in a CTF with multiple people at once? Unfortunately because of our internal process I can't use online sources for this and need to host something local.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. What sort of race condition are you looking for?

Comment: @Limit As per the tags a web application that has an intentional race condition flaw. The language doesn't matter since it's not the point of the exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Back in 2011, Taylor Hornby wrote a TOCTTOU vulnerable PHP web application that is often found in banks and such that can cause Race Condition bugs, its a cool application.

The application is well explained in https://defuse.ca/race-conditions-in-web-applications.htm and I think can become a useful resource. (it explains a lot of issues and responses to each)